# Construction of R-tree data structure for tiling polygon vector data

Tags: vector-tiles, rtree, tiling, tiling-scheme

Because it is better for irregular distributed data, I want to create tiles using r-tree for my dataset. My dataset consists of 1214 polygons which represents building foorprints. After doing some research about r-tree implementations, I could not find answers for some questions. So I don't know where to start. Here are questions which I want to find their answers:

1- Every article that I read mentions minimum and maximum entries (m and M) for nodes of the tree but did not mention how to calculate them. Or if we assume some predefined values, for my data set which values must be m and M?

2- How can we determine the level of the tree?

3- I want to construct rtree and return all child nodes and their bounds such as following example ;

```
mbr=Rectangle [x1=10.0, y1=4.0, x2=62.0, y2=85.0]
  mbr=Rectangle [x1=28.0, y1=4.0, x2=34.0, y2=85.0]
    entry=Entry [value=2, geometry=Point [x=29.0, y=4.0]]
    entry=Entry [value=1, geometry=Point [x=28.0, y=19.0]]
    entry=Entry [value=4, geometry=Point [x=34.0, y=85.0]]
  mbr=Rectangle [x1=10.0, y1=45.0, x2=62.0, y2=63.0]
    entry=Entry [value=5, geometry=Point [x=62.0, y=45.0]]
    entry=Entry [value=3, geometry=Point [x=10.0, y=63.0]]
```

Are there any python library for this purpose ??

here is my data set [image]

Comment: http://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/ explains how to use the python modul rtree with vector data.

Comment: yes but seems it does not return non leaf nodes and their bounds. It returns only intersected bounds for any given geometry

Comment: What do you *really* want to do? http://xyproblem.info/